# LDAP / AD integration for desktop .net application: does it make sense?

Tags: .net, windows, security, active-directory, ldap

I have a customer that is requesting to integrate LDAP / AD login of Windows with a desktop .NET application. It's a desktop .NET application meaning it's not a webpage which is publicly accessible: it's an executable with GUI that will run as a program (not as service) under Windows which is locally copied on the computer.

The customer is requesting this as a measure of security. When you open the application you enter username and password and do an authentication check with LDAP.
I don't really understand against what security risk this is supposed to protect:

- The application is running under Windows so a Windows user must already be logged in -> What's the point of checking the credentials both on windows login and application login?
- The only scenario I can think of is if someone leaves his computer unattended while he is logged in to Windows, in which case someone else can start the application: however it doesn't prevent the scenario in which someone leaves his computer unattended while he is logged in to Windows and also logged in to the application. It doesn't make sense to invest time in protecting against one scenario and not the other, both are as likely to happen.

I have asked my contact with the customer, but his answer basically comes down to "because it's company policy" so I don't think he really understands it either.
Can you think of reasons why you want this? What are the security risks against which it protects?

Comment: Reminds me of the [Chrome password manager debarcle](http://blog.elliottkember.com/chromes-insane-password-security-strategy). I agree with you - employees should be trained to lock their computer when unattended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to touch up on comparison of LDAP auth vs MySQL, why LDAP is more scalability, fast, why not RDBMS so on here. I will just give you an idea in general.

First of all, if the answer "because it's company policy" then I can assure you that you cannot win because it is a cliche one. You get an answer like that often when people have very little knowledge about what they want and what they are told by mister know-it-all!

Applications are secure only if the users use them properly and developers develop them properly.

> Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to
>   build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying
>   to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning —
>   Rich Cook.

Back to your question, LDAP auth provides some common kind of security (I've developed a few LDAP auth apps and all of them were same because the process is always the same). The main reason to keep and manage accounts in one place, that's all. It can be called security and a company policy. I think they are more concerned about two steps below.

- John joins the company, IT manager creates his email account in AD,
  assigns him to some OUs (organisational units). John uses the app but
  he can only **use certain features** of the app based on his OUs that
  come from LDAP auth (a big set of array/object). Security level is
  defined like that.
- John leaves the company, IT manager disables/deleted his account in
  AD and John cannot login the system anymore. System is automatically
  secured like that.

Making the app available on desktop environment might have security reasons behind it but has nothing to do with LDAP so it is just a "policy".

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense, provided your desktop application is used to make approvals. I have used many applications (eg: change management apps) which require you to login before you can use and at every approval.

This authentication & authorization of user becomes critical, especially if your Customer has to be FDA / [GxP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GxP) Compliant (21 CFR Part 11.10) [Search [here](http://www.21cfrpart11.com/files/fda_docs/validation_draft_postres.pdf) for the term 'Digital'] which emphasizes that the Software should take care to ensure that the person needs to be authenticated against a valid source. This can be AD authentication, SMART Cards, etc...

Comment: Interesting remark about requiring additional login at every important approval/change in the application. However there was no such requirement for the application in this case: only at startup.

Comment: @user968698 login would be mandatory if your Customer has to be FDA / GxP compliant or if this application is going to be operating in a 'validated' enviroment